# ¿Cómo imprimir el contenido de un objeto que contiene una lista de objetos?

Tags: java

El programa en si es una aplicación que se presentaría por la consola solamente. Se debe permitir el ingreso, consulta, modificaron y eliminación de estudiantes, profesores, secretarios, conserjes y calificaciones.

Se debe ingresar como un tipo de usuario y cada tipo de usuario tiene ciertas limitaciones:

En este caso estamos desarrollando el apartado del administrador, el cual puede hacer todo. El problema surge al momento de consultar los datos ya ingresados del objeto Estudiante, todo se presenta correctamente a excepción de la lista de materias que es lo ultimo que se debe presentar, la cual al momento de presentarse presenta la dirección en la cual esta guardada (En la siguiente imagen se puede ver lo que se presenta).

En un principio estaba pensado usar el método `mostrarM()` de la clase `Materia` pero debido a que `Materia` esta declarada como una Lista dentro de `Estudiante`, no se puede poner el `.mostrarM()`, desconozco si es algún error en la estructura o declaración de atributo o clases.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podría hacer para que se presenten los datos de esa lista?

Código realizado actualmente:

**Parte del código que permite la presentación de datos**

```
public static void mostrarDatos(LinkedList lista)
    {
        Persona p;
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();++i)
        {
            p=(Persona)lista.get(i);
            System.out.println(i+" - "+p.mostrar());
        }
    }
```

**Parte del código que permite el ingreso de datos**

```
public static void ingresoDatos(int Tipo,LinkedList lista)
    {
        String nombre,apellido,cedula,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestreC;
        String carreras,materiasD,turno;
        int i,edad,años_servicio,año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg,cant_materias,parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion;
        
        String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestreM, id_carrera;
        
        Calificaciones calificaciones;
        Materia materias;
        List<Materia> materias_semestre;
        materias_semestre = new ArrayList<Materia>();
        
        Fecha f_nacimiento;
        Fecha f_inicio;
        Fecha f_final;
        Fecha f_ingreso;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre:");
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido:");
            apellido=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su cedula:");
            cedula=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
            edad=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            f_nacimiento= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su telefono:");
            telefono=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su direccion:");
            direccion=sc.nextLine();
            
        
        if (Tipo == 1){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su semestre:");
            semestreC=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_inicio= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_final= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese Catidad Materias:");
            cant_materias=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_materias;i++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre Materia:");
                nombre_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Codigo Materia:");
                codigo_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Semestre Materia:");
                semestreM=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese ID Materia:");
                id_carrera=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Parcial 1 de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                parcial1=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Parcial 2 de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                parcial2=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Recuperacion de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                recuperacion=sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
                
                calificaciones = new Calificaciones(parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion);
                materias= new Materia(nombre_materia,codigo_materia,semestreM,id_carrera,calificaciones);
                materias_semestre.add(materias);
            }

            lista.add(new Estudiante(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestreC,f_inicio,f_final,materias_semestre));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 2){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus carreras:");
            carreras=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese materias que dicta:");
            materiasD=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Profesor(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carreras,materiasD));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 3){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_ingreso=new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana o tarde):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 4){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_ingreso=new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana, tarde o noche):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
    }
```

*Codigo Principal*

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProyectoPOO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TipoPersona,Sistema=1,Accion,Aux,Tipo;
        
        LinkedList LE= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LP= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LS= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LC= new LinkedList();
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su tipo de usuario:");
            System.out.println("1. Estudiante");
            System.out.println("2. Profesor");
            System.out.println("3. Secretario");
            System.out.println("4. Conserje");
            System.out.println("5. Administrador");
            System.out.println("6. Salir");
            TipoPersona=sc.nextInt();
            switch(TipoPersona){
            
            case 1: //Estudiante
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 2: //Profesor
                do{
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("2. Modificar Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("3. Consultar Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("4. Cierre de Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("5. Consulta tipo acta de calificación de estudiante por materia");
                System.out.println("6. Retroceder");
                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch(Accion){
                        case 1: //Ingreso de Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 2: //Modificar Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 3: //Consultar Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 4: //Cierre de Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 5: //Consulta tipo acta de calificación de estudiante por materia
                        break;
                        case 6: //Retroceder
                        Sistema=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }while(Sistema==1);
                Sistema=1;
            break;
            
            case 3: //Secretario
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 4: //Conserje
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 5: //Administrador
                do{
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
                System.out.println("1. Modificar Estudiantes");
                System.out.println("2. Modificar Profesores");
                System.out.println("3. Modificar Secretarias");
                System.out.println("4. Modificar Conserjes");
                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch(Accion){
                        case 1: //Estudiantes
                            Tipo=1;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Estudiantes?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Estudiantes");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Estudiante
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LE);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size()); //Para asegurar q se guardan los objetos
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Estudiantes
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Estudiante
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del estudiante del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LE);
                                        LE.set(Aux,LE.getLast());
                                        LE.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Estudiante a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LE.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 2: //Profesores
                            Tipo=2;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Profesores?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Profesores");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar profesor
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LP);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar profesor
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos profesor
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del eprofesor del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LP);
                                        LP.set(Aux,LP.getLast());
                                        LP.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar profesor
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del profesor a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LP.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 3: //Secretarios
                            Tipo=3;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Secretarios?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Secretario");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar SecretarioS");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Secretario");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Secretario");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Secretario
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LS);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Secretario
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Secretario
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Secretario del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LS);
                                        LS.set(Aux,LS.getLast());
                                        LS.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Secretario a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LS.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 4: //Conserje
                            Tipo=4;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de ConserjeS?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Conserje");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Conserjes");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Conserje");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Conserje");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Conserje
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LC);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Conserje
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Conserje
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Conserje del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LC);
                                        LC.set(Aux,LC.getLast());
                                        LC.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Conserje a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LC.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 5: //Retroceder
                        Sistema=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }while(Sistema==1);
                Sistema=1;
            break;
            case 6: //Salir del Sistema
                Sistema=0;
            break;}
        }while(Sistema==1);

    }
```

*Clase Abstracta Persona*

```
public abstract class Persona{
    
    protected String nombre,apellido,cedula,telefono,direccion;
    protected int edad;
    protected Fecha f_nacimiento;
    
    public Persona(String nombre,String apellido,String cedula,int edad,Fecha f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion)
    {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.cedula=cedula;
        this.edad=edad;
        this.f_nacimiento=f_nacimiento;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.direccion=direccion;
    }
    
    public abstract String mostrar();
    
}
```

*Clase Estudiante*

```
import java.util.*;
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    
    protected String carrera,semestre;
    protected List<Materia> materias_semestre;
    protected Fecha f_inicio,f_final;
    
    public Estudiante(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, int edad, Fecha f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carrera,String semestre,Fecha f_inicio,Fecha f_final,List<Materia> materias_semestre){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carrera=carrera;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.f_inicio=f_inicio;
        this.f_final=f_final;
        this.materias_semestre=materias_semestre;
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
        
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento.mostrarF()+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+semestre+" "+f_inicio.mostrarF()+" "+f_final.mostrarF()+" "+materias_semestre);
    }

}
```

*Clase Materia*

```
public class Materia {
    
    protected String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestre, id_carrera;
    protected Calificaciones calificaciones;
    
    public Materia(String nombre_materia,String codigo_materia, String semestre, String id_carrera, Calificaciones calificaciones)
    {
        this.nombre_materia=nombre_materia;
        this.codigo_materia=codigo_materia;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.id_carrera=id_carrera;
        this.calificaciones=calificaciones;
    }
  
    public String mostrarM(){
        
        return nombre_materia+"/"+codigo_materia+"/"+semestre+"--"+id_carrera+":"+calificaciones.mostrarC();
    }

}
```

*Clase Calificación*

```
public class Calificaciones {
    
    protected int parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion;
    
    public Calificaciones(int parcial1,int parcial2,int recuperacion)
    {
        this.parcial1=parcial1;
        this.parcial2=parcial2;
        this.recuperacion=recuperacion;
        //this.nota_final=nota_final;
    }
  
    public String mostrarC(){
        if ((parcial1+parcial2)/2>=7){
            
            return parcial1+"/"+parcial2+"/ Nota Final:"+(parcial1+parcial2)/2;
        }
        else{
            return parcial1+"/"+parcial2+"/"+recuperacion+"/ Nota Final:"+(((parcial1+parcial2)/2)*0.6)+(recuperacion*0.4);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar en qué parte del código intentas imprimir la lista? Así nos evitar tratar de adivinar dónde es. ¿Podrías decirnos también por qué no usas el método `mostrarM()` de la clase `Materia`?

Comment: Editado, para una mayor comprensión, espero que se logre comprender.

Comment: Dado que has declarado esto: `List<Materia> materias_semestre` entonces puedes iterar la lista y usar con cada elemento el método `mostrarM()` porque cada elemento de la lista será un objeto `Materia`

Comment: @LuisAlbertoVeraGarcia puedes publicar unicamente el codigo que genera error y no toda la app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema radica en el método `mostrar` de la clase `Estudiante`:

```java
public String mostrar()
{ 
        
   return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento.mostrarF()+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+semestre+" "+f_inicio.mostrarF()+" "+f_final.mostrarF()+" "+materias_semestre);                                                                                       
}
```

Al final del `return` has puesto simplemente `materias_semestre`, esto en realidad invoca al método `toString` de la clase `LinkedList` (en este caso, claro), pero como la clase `Materia` en ningún momento sobrescribe el método `toString`, invorá al método [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) que hereda la clase `Materia` de `Object`.

Y tal como dice la documentación del método `toString` de la clase [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Traducción a español:

> El método `toString` de la clase `Object` devuelve una cadena que consta del nombre de la clase, el carácter de signo arroba '@' y la representación hexadecimal sin signo del código hash del objeto.

En pocas palabras, te muestra eso en pantalla porque se está invocando al método `toString` de la clase `Object` y claramente el resultado reflejará el nombre de la clase + el código hash del objeto.

**Solución:** Sobrescribe el método `toString` en la clase `Materia`:

```java
public class Materia {
    
    protected String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestre, id_carrera;
    protected Calificaciones calificaciones;
    
    public Materia(String nombre_materia,String codigo_materia, String semestre, String id_carrera, Calificaciones calificaciones)
    {
        this.nombre_materia=nombre_materia;
        this.codigo_materia=codigo_materia;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.id_carrera=id_carrera;
        this.calificaciones=calificaciones;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        
        return nombre_materia+"/"+codigo_materia+"/"+semestre+"--"+id_carrera+":"+calificaciones.mostrarC();
    }

}
```

**Recomendación:**

Sí quieres representar textualmente el contenido del objeto, sobrescribe el método `toString`, no te inventes el nombre.

Por ejemplo, en vez de usar el nombre `mostrarC` en la clase `Calificacion`, ¡sobrescribe el método `toString`!

Esto evita problemas cuando quieras saber cual es el contenido del objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la libreria `lombok` usando esta libreria podrias usar la anotacion @ToString y automaticamente te convertira todos los elementos dentro de un array en String